# Laravel 6 - How to fix routing to/returns a blank page

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing

I am routing a user if the user clicked the button from the dropdown menu but it only redirects me to a blank page.

**Picture of button from dropdown:**

[image]

**Picture of the blank page:**

[image]

**Snippet code of dropdown menu:**

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->first_name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    @can('manage-agent')
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('agent.flightManagement') }}">
                                        <i class="fa fa-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        Flight Management
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                        <i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        Booking Management
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                        <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        User Management
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                        <i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        Passenger Management
                                    </a>
                                    <hr>
                                    @endcan
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                        onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                        document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                            <i class="fa fa-power-off" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        Logout
                                    </a>
                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
```

**Snippet code of web.php:**

```
Route::namespace('Agent')->middleware('can:manage-agent')->group(function(){
    Route::resource('/agent', 'AgentsController');
    Route::get('agent/flightManagement', 'AgentsController@flightManagement')->name('agent.flightManagement');
    Route::post('/agent/store', 'AgentsController@store')->name('agent.store');
});
```

**Snippet code of flightManagement function inside the AgentsController:**

```
public function flightManagement()
    {
        return view('agent\flightManagement');
    }
```

I don't know what causes this problem because it only shows a blank page and there is no error even in browser's console but in the **laravel.log** file it shows this:

> [previous exception] [object]
> (Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException(code:
> 0): Route [flightManagement] not defined. at
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ChingChong_Airlines\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php:420)
> [stacktrace]
>
> ## 0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ChingChong_Airlines\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php(782):
>
> Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator->route('flightManagemen...', Array,
> true)
>
> ## 1 C:\xampp\htdocs\ChingChong_Airlines\storage\framework\views\8d22c5f09df43b073d10fd0d1dc7f6aa250603dd.php(73):
>
> route('flightManagemen...')

Comment: Somewhere in your blade file, lookup for `flightManagement` and replace it with `agent.flightManagement`

Comment: I think it's something like `route('flightManagement')`; should be `route('agent.flightManagement')`

Comment: i have already route('agent.flightManagement'). route('flightManagement') returns this error: Route [flightManagement] not defined.

Comment: That's what @user8555937 was trying to tell you: there is no `route('flightManagement')` defined, use `route('agent.flightManagement')` instead

Comment: @kerbholz still does not solve the problem

Answer (score -1):

Try to re-create a new view with different name, like helpers-working.php

Comment: How is that related to the question? How does this solve a routing problem?